# TSC hangs on compile after reinstall

Tags: angular, typescript

I had to re-install everything from scratch on my development machine and was getting "TSC not a recognized command" from the command line.  I need this for an Angular 7 project.

Fine, I considered adding to PATH but since everything was re-installed I went via NPM using:

`npm install -g typescript`

TSC now hangs on compile (or transpile, if you prefer) which prior to the re-install was compiling this project without issue.

Any suggestions?  Is this possibly due to a TypeScript version issue of some sort?

Can I get any additional info from TSC via a command line switch to show me why this is hanging?

Edit: Is this related to the following Github issue and the dupe about extremely slow response times?

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30745

TSC 3.7.4 so shouldn't be.